# How to count number of columns in a View? - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I'm trying to figure out a way to count the number of columns in a view in Oracle. There's a lot of answers around on how to count the number of columns in a table, but none for views.

The database has many, many views, and I have to count for each one. It would be most efficient to find a solution in the form of a query I can repeatedly execute - hand counting isn't going to work here.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
      table_name,
      column_name,
      data_type
 FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'VIEWNAME'
  AND owner      = 'OWNER'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

for counting

```
SELECT
  count(*) columnCount
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'VIEWNAME'
  AND owner      = 'OWNER'
```

Answer (score 2):

The views are in `dba_views` for all views in the database or in `all_views` for all views the current user can access. The columns are in `dba_tab_cols` or `all_tab_cols`. (There is also `user_views` and `user_tab_cols` for the objects owned by the current user.)

You need a join or an `IN` or `EXISTS` clause, because the `xxx_tab_cols` views don't only contain view columns, but also table columns.

```
select owner, table_name as view_name, count(*)
from dba_tab_cols
where (owner, table_name) in (select owner, view_name from dba_views)
group by owner, table_name
order by owner, view_name;
```